# `operator>>' is not a member of `Instance'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have the `InstancePool` class (part of it below) with the Instance.h header included, but I get the error in the title in the `operator>>` function of `InstancePool`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#include "Instance.h"
#include "InstancePool.h"

istream &operator >> (istream &in , InstancePool &ip) {

    ip.Instances->clear();

    string input;
    getline(in , input);

    while (!in.eof()) {

        Instance inst;

        Instance::operator >>(in , inst); // <- line giving me the error

        ip.Instances->push_back(inst);

        getline(in , input);

    }
}
```

The InstancePool operator>> function is a 'friend' function BTW, and so is the same function in Instance. Probably I'm trying to access the Instance 'operator>>' in the wrong way but I'll be damned if I know the correct one...
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Friend functions aren’t member functions, you cannot explicitly qualify the function’s name the way you did because it’s simply not inside a namespace called `Instance`.

The good news is: you don’t need to. Just call it normally:

```
in >> inst;
```

There are more bugs in your code, though. First off, `while (in.eof())` will result in an infinite loop when there’s an error while reading – **never** do this.

Second of all, you’re reading and discarding lines with `getline`. This is probably not what you want to do, right? Do you want to read each instance from the line or directly from the input stream?

Comment: Yes, I thought using eof() would result in something really bad..
I believe I should read it directly from the iput stream.Any suggestions?Thank you for your time!

Comment: @user2055832 Yes, read it directly in the loop: `Instance inst; while (in >> inst) ip.Instances->push_back(inst);` might work, depending on how the objects are read individually.

Comment: Hmm I see. I'll try it that way and report back in case of problems! Thank you!